# How to check that I'm dealing with a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm learning Haskell, and I'm trying to add preconditions to a (trivial, as an exercise) `element_at` function (code below). I've created a "helper" `elem_at_r` because otherwise, `len x` fails at some point (when x is a 'literal' rather than a list? - I still have trouble parsing ghci's error messages). `elem_at` now has all the error checking, and `elem_at_r` does the work. In `elem_at`, I'd like to add a check that `x` is indeed a list (and not a 'literal'). How can I do that?

```
len x = sum [ 1 | a <- x]

elem_at_r x n | n == 0     = head x
              | 0 < n      = elem_at_r (tail x) (n-1)

elem_at x n | x == []    = error "Need non-empty list"
            | len x <= n = error "n too large " ++ show (len x)
            | n < 0      = error "Need positive n"
            | otherwise  = elem_at_r x n
```

Thanks!

Frank

Comment: Wait, wat? The type system will make sure it's a list. `len :: [a] -> a` so `x` must be `[a]`, i.e. a list. If it isn't, that's a compiletime error. And unlike some much-despised functions, `len` won't throw an `error` for *any* list - why would it?. Please specify "len x fails".

Comment: Could you please paste the error message you cannot parse? I could help you deciphering it. That you get an error message when you pass something else than a list is expected - The error message probably just tells you that GHCi can't figure out how the input can be a list.

Comment: And BTW, all your error-conditions are special cases of the second one.

Comment: The error message was ghci complaining with me calling elem_at with 3 and 3: elem_at 3 3. Now I understand, the type system is catching that the first '3' is not a list. If I had been compiling, the compiler would have stopped me, right?

Answer (score 4):

Due to Haskell's type system, `elem_at` can *only* take a list as its first argument (`x`); if you try to pass a non-list, GHC will detect this and give an error at compile time (or interpretation time in GHCi).  I don't know why `len` would "fail"; could you post the error message that GHCi gives you?

Comment: More specifically, it's an example of [Type Inference](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type_inference)

Comment: Please bear with me, I'm a beginner at Haskell :-) "Fail" was probably not the right word. Here is the original code and the ghci error message I'm seeing: elem_at x n | x == []    = error "Need non-empty list"
            | len x <= n = error "n too large " ++ show (len x)
            | n < 0      = error "Need positive n"
            | n == 0     = head x
            | 0 < n      = elem_at (tail x) (n-1)

Comment: Sorry for the formatting: *Main Data.Typeable> elem_at [1,2,3] 2

<interactive>:1:14:
    No instance for (Num [Char])
      arising from the literal `3'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [Char])
    In the expression: 3
    In the first argument of `elem_at', namely `[1, 2, 3]'
    In the expression: elem_at [1, 2, 3] 2

Comment: @Frank: Were you trying to use the return value of `elem_at [1,2,3] 2` as a `String` (a type synonym for `[Char]` which the literal value `3` cannot be converted to implicitly)?  Without more code and/or context, that's the only explanation for the error I can think of.

Comment: I'm just on the command line in ghci trying my trivial function to see if I coded the exercise properly. That's the context, it's not part of a larger program that would try to use the returned value.

Comment: @jwodder: if you put in function signatures you'll get a more useful error message....

Comment: :-) - got it. I thought I could dispense with types to make the code more concise but I see everybody is telling me they are useful :-)

Comment: Many times I put in signatures if I can't understand the errors ghci / ghc gives me. Once I fix the errors, I can (but usually don't) do away with the signatures. One advantage of removing the signatures is that ghc can sometimes make the function general enough that it works for more types than you envisioned. For example, if the signature of elem_at was "elem_at [Int] -> Int" and you remove it, the function magically works on all lists, not just Int's.

Comment: Tim - I rewrote the code with your pattern matching and type signatures, and I can't load the function anymore... Couldn't match type `a' with `[Char]'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for elem_at :: [a] -> Int -> a
          at exercise-99-1.hs:36:1
    In the expression: (error "n too large " ++ show (len x))

Comment: @Frank: Think of the type signatures as telling GHC what you're expecting something to be. That way, if you're wrong, it will tell you what expectation was violated, instead of just trying its best to find something that works and then complaining wherever it gets stuck.

Comment: @Frank: Check your indentation. I just cut-n-pasted the code from my post into a file and it worked.

Comment: @Frank: generally I write my functions in a file and load them into ghci using ":l <filename>". Trying to cut-n-paste my code directly into ghci will lead to errors. It is possible if you add some curly brackets and have patience. I don't have patience so I use ":l". There is a post either on stack overflow or in the Haskell Beginners mailing list telling how to do it the other way

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were getting errors because of the "x == []" line. The code below pattern matches for that condition and adds a few signatures. Otherwise it is the same. Hope it helps.

```
len x = sum [ 1 | a <- x]

elem_at_r :: [a] -> Int -> a
elem_at_r x n | n == 0     = head x
              | 0 < n      = elem_at_r (tail x) (n-1)

elem_at :: [a] -> Int -> a
elem_at [] _ = error "Need non-empty list"
elem_at x n | len x <= n = error ("n too large " ++ show (len x))
            | n < 0      = error "Need positive n"
            | otherwise  = elem_at_r x n
```

You could also make your helper functions part of this function using a where clause:

```
elem_at :: [a] -> Int -> a
elem_at [] _ = error "Need non-empty list"
elem_at x n | len x <= n = error ("n too large " ++ show (len x))
            | n < 0      = error "Need positive n"
            | otherwise  = elem_at_r x n 
  where
    len :: [a] -> Int 
    len x = sum [ 1 | a <- x]

    elem_at_r :: [a] -> Int -> a
    elem_at_r x n | n == 0     = head x
                  | 0 < n      = elem_at_r (tail x) (n-1)
```

Comment: Just an extra question: adding type signatures is nice for documentation, but it works without, and I like concise code. Can I dispense with writing those type signatures?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy replies! Greatly helps!

Comment: One more thing, I can't pattern match [] _ right after a |, right? - IMHO, it would be cuter.

Comment: You know, I don't know about that pattern match. You might consult Real World Haskell or Learn You a Haskell for Great Good.

Comment: Type signatures tend to force GHC (and ghci) to give more useful errors. However, no, they are not necessary.

Comment: I'm in the middle of reading those 2 references. I thought I could do some Prolog-like "pattern matching" anywhere. Thanks a lot for the answers.

Comment: @Frank: Sorry, nope. It's basically `function_name [pattern_matches] | boolean_predicate = expression`. However, if the predicates don't handle all cases, it will fall through to the next pattern match, so you can still use guards to select which matches you want, in a way.

Comment: @camccann: thanks. I was going to say that but I wasn't positive.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. I wanted to do pattern matching inside the boolean predicate, i.e. have the predicate return a true/false value AND bind x and xs in (x:xs) for me... I'm guessing that's not in line with Haskell's philosophy (no side-effects?)?

Comment: That is, if the pattern matches, it's a "true", if it doesn't it's a "false" - I'm guessing Haskell won't have any of that kind of reasoning :-)

Comment: Well, you can only pattern match on constructors and the pattern (x:xs) means there is a value "x" that is cons'd ":" onto a list. But if you have an empty list, there is no value cons'd onto a list. Note the list in "xs" can be either empty [] or a value cons'd onto the rest of the list.

Comment: @Frank: How does that differ from just pattern matching? If you have `elem_at (x:xs) n = ...` then it will either match the `:` constructor and bind `x` and `xs`, or it will fail to match (i.e., if you give it `[]`) and fall through to the next pattern.

Comment: @Frank: As a more explicit example, your two definitions for `elem_at_r` could be written as `elem_at_r (x:_) 0 = x` and `elem_at_r (_:xs) n | 0 < n = elem_at_r xs (n - 1)`

Comment: Yes, makes sense. I was experimenting with the syntax, and wanted to have everything under a single "heading", using | to provide all the alternatives.

Comment: @camccann: I like your solution very much.